# Настройка django-guardians

Tags: python, django, access, django-admin

Помогите разобраться почему вылетает ошибка:

```
GuardianError at /courses/1/modules
If model should be looked up from string it needs format: 'app_label.ModelClass'
```

Код:

```
@permission_required_or_403('courses.view_Course', (Group, 'users_with_subscribe'))
def all_modules(request, course_id):
    course = get_object_or_404(Course, id=course_id)
    modules = course.modules.all()
    return render(request, 'modules.html', {'modules': modules, 'course_id' : course_id, 'progress' : calculate_course_progress(request.user, course)})
``

Нужно, чтобы доступ к конкретному курсу осуществлялся через админку. В админке я задал разрешение на просмотр Курсов для группы users_with_subscribe
```